# How to print specific lines in a file that was appended from a loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, with-statement

```
from itertools import zip_longest 
f = open("all_info.txt", "a")
with open("all_info.txt") as f, open ("over_speeding.txt") as f1, open("fine.txt") as fine, open("all details.txt", "a") as everything:
     for fline, fineline in zip_longest (f, fine, fillvalue=""): 
          everything.write (fineline.strip() + "   ---   " + fline.strip() + "\n")      


          a = open("all details.txt", "r")
          for line in everything:#the problem
               everything.strip()
               if line in f1:
                    with ("fine1.txt", "a") as fine1:
                         fine1.write(line)
```

This is just a part of my whole code. My whole code takes vehicle registration number then checks if it is standard or not. then time taken to travel 1 mile is entered which is used to calculate the speed.

if the speed is greater than 70mph the registration number and the speed the vehicle was travelling goes to the file over_speeding.txt. then the other conditions determine which file does the details go (but this is not important).

The code that i have shown you will open 4 files, where the fine.txt file is already set and the over_speeding.txt files gets its data from my whole code. all_info.txt file will store all the inputs from my whole code then using the zip_lingest module all_info.txt file is appended with fine.txt to all_details.txt file.

what i want just to select the lines in all details.txt that are overspeeding, then save it to fine1.txt

e.g. fine.txt

```
11111
22222
33333
44444
```

all_info.txt

```
xxxxxxxx
dddddddd
aaaaaaaa
cccccccc
```

all_details.txt

```
11111 --- xxxxxxxx
22222 --- dddddddd
33333 --- aaaaaaaa
44444 --- cccccccc
```

if

```
xxxxxxx
```

and

```
aaaaaaa
```

were from the file over_speeding.txt, then in the all details.txt file:

```
11111 --- xxxxxxxx
33333 --- aaaaaaaa
```

should be saved into fine1.txt file

Comment: Your constant opening and reopening of the same files leads to problems. `all details.txt` gets opened twice, and then you refer to it as `everything` again.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Did you solve it? If my answer is not satisfactory, please provide more detail or tell me, what doesn't work.

Comment: yep i did i had to make some changes to what u gave but thank you for suggesting

Answer (score 1):

I had problems understanding your code (the names for variables are not really helpful, when someone tries to read your code, at least for me), but I've tried to rewrite it doing what you expected it to do:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
#EDIT why open all_info.txt twice?
#f = open("all_info.txt", "a")
with open("all_info.txt", "a") as f,\
    open("over_speeding.txt") as f1,\
    open("fine.txt") as fine,\
    open("all details.txt", "a") as everything,\
    open("fine1.txt", "a") as fine1: # moved opening fine1 here

    for fline, fineline in zip_longest(f, fine, fillvalue=""):
        #EDIT
        line_to_write = fineline.strip() + "   ---   " + fline.strip() # so we don't need to write it twice
        everything.write(line_to_write + "\n") # write to file with newline
        if line_to_write in f1: # compare the line with values in over_speeding
            fine1.write(line_to_write)
```

As it is only part of a script and I don't have all the data I could not test it. Your approach: write all the lines to everything and then check all the lines separately. My approach: get the line, write it and check it in the same loop. If I understood your code, it should do the same. Please ask or point to any mistakes/misunderstandings.

Comment: sorry this doesnt work. but if u want i can show you my full code then you will get a better understanding

Comment: And did you understand the things I've changed and why (maybe you could adjust it, simple copy & paste won't work)? If you want you can send me git link or something like that and I'll have a look.